# Chess software that enables you to set up a position from scratch?

Tags: analysis, software

I'm looking for chess software (free or otherwise) that will allow me to completely clear the board and set it up as I wish in order to analyze a specific situation. All of the chess puzzle software I've seen seems to have only pre-loaded positions to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm getting back into playing and not familiar with what's out there now for software.

Comment: The screenshot is of ChessBase 15. Actually, that feature has not changed since ChessBase 1 back in 1990. ChessBase is the leader, and granddaddy, of chess software.

Comment: What about lichess.org https://lichess.org/editor?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what platform you are using, but on Android I use the "[Analyze This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pereira.analysis)" app - it lets you set up positions from scratch, and also use an engine to analyze.  There is a free version of the app, and a paid "Pro" version.  In the free version, the only available engine is Stockfish; in the "Pro" version, you can add other UCI engines.

Answer (score 1):

ChessBase, or even the lesser priced Fritz, allow you to do that. Just open a board, and type in "S", and it will let you put in whatever position you want. (They both allow you to then analyze from there.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most general-purpose chess software has this feature, usually under "Edit Board" or similar menu entries.

On Linux, usually there are two components to the software which are developed independently - a board program and a playing engine; the latter acts as an opponent or an analyser.  The board program, such as Scid or Xboard, is where you would look for the board setup functions.

On Windows, the popular chess engines usually come with their own board front-ends.  Crafty is a decent free option.

It's also possible to use an online browser-based platform such as LiChess.

Answer (score 0):

Lichess as a website - as mentioned by Chromatix - offers the [Board editor](https://lichess.org/editor) online and in the [app](https://lichess.org/mobile). Lichess is free software.